# ¿Como poner reproducción automatica en swiper (carousel)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

quisiera que me puedan apoyar con este tema, lo que pasa es que muestro imagenes atravez de swiper, lo malo es que no se reproduce automaticamente y tengo que usar las flechas, el cliente quiere que sea automatico, aquí una imagen de como lo muestro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código :

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="assets/images/single-property/s-1.jpg" class="grid image-link">
                <img src="assets/images/single-property/s-1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="assets/images/single-property/s-2.jpg" class="grid image-link">
                <img src="assets/images/single-property/s-2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="assets/images/single-property/s-3.jpg" class="grid image-link">
                <img src="assets/images/single-property/s-3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="#">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white mr-3"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white ml-3"></div>
</div>
```

Una solución fue:

```
<script>
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        autoplay: {
            delay: 5000,
        },
    });
</script>
```

Pero el problema es que solo me muestra una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué tipo de slide estás usando? Tal vez sea tu css, porque el autoplay a mí me funciona bien

Comment: Es posible que tú bootstrap haga conflicto con tu estilo de swiper